# Firebase Child_Added Not Working In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a random chatting website somewhat like Omegle with Firebase Realtime Database. I have accomplished most of the tasks I needed. I am using nodejs to decide whom to connect with the other stranger. The code below is working fine but some of the javascript code is not working as expected. I have mentioned that code in the next code snippet.

The Whole HTML + Javascript File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Connect to the Firebase
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      var id;
      var chattingWithKey='None';
      var chattingWithName;
      var msgs;
      var myName = "<?php echo $_POST["uname"]; ?>";
      var gender = "<?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?>";
      var locality;
      var country;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "compass-testing000",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();

      //Signing Anonymously
      firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(function(){
      // alert('User Register successfully');
      id=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      firebase.database().ref('connected/'+ id).set({ 
        chattingWith : 'None'
      });
        
   }).catch(function(error){

    var errorcode=error.code;
    var errormsg=error.message;
   });

                        function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
                        if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
                            var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
                            var theta = lon1-lon2;
                            var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
                            var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
                            if (dist > 1) {
                                dist = 1;
                            }
                            dist = Math.acos(dist);
                            dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
                            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
                            if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
                            if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
                            return dist;
                        }
                    }

    function watchLocation(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    successCallback = successCallback || function(){};
    errorCallback = errorCallback || function(){};

  // Try HTML5-spec geolocation.
  var geolocation = navigator.geolocation;

  if (geolocation) {
    // We have a real geolocation service.
    try {
      function handleSuccess(position) {
        successCallback(position.coords);
      }

      geolocation.watchPosition(handleSuccess, errorCallback, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 4000 // 4 sec.
      });
    } catch (err) {
      errorCallback();
    }
  } else {
    errorCallback();
  }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
                watchLocation(function(coords) {
                document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'COORDS: ' + coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude;
                
                xhr.open('GET', 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat='+coords.latitude+'&lon='+coords.longitude+'&zoom=18&addressdetails=1', true); 
                xhr.send(); 
                xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest; 
                xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false); 
                function processRequest(e) {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { 
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
                        locality = response.address.city;
                        country = response.address.country_code;
                        //console.log(locality +' '+country); 
                        return; 
                    }
                }
            if(id && country){
            //Sending Data to the Firebase
            firebase.database().ref('users/'+id).set(
            {   
                name: myName,
                gender: gender,
                latitude: coords.latitude,
                longitude: coords.longitude,
                country: country,
                locality: locality,
                online: true,
            });
            var ref1 = firebase.database().ref('connected/'+id);
            ref1.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                    chattingWithKey = snapshot.val().chattingWith;
                });
                
                if(chattingWithKey != 'None')
                {
                    //Retrive Data from Firebase and show in Realtime
                    var ref = firebase.database().ref('users/'+chattingWithKey);
                    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                            //console.log(snapshot.val().latitude +' '+ snapshot.val().longitude);
                            if(distance(coords.latitude, coords.longitude, snapshot.val().latitude , snapshot.val().longitude ,'K'))
                            document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = distance(coords.latitude, coords.longitude, snapshot.val().latitude , snapshot.val().longitude ,'K') + ' Kilometers';
                        
                    }, function (error) {
                       console.log("Error: " + error.code);
                    });
                    
                        firebase.database().ref('messages/'+id).limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.val().sender == myName) {
                            let name = snapshot.val().sender;
                            let value = snapshot.val().message;
                            let div = document.createElement("div");
                            let span = document.createElement("span");
                            span.innerHTML = "@"+ name;
                            let p = document.createElement("p");
                            p.innerHTML = value;
                            
                            div.appendChild(span);
                            div.appendChild(p);
                            
                            msgs.appendChild(div);
                            msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
                            console.log(snapshot.val().sender+': '+snapshot.val().message);
                        }
                        });
                        
                        firebase.database().ref('messages/'+chattingWithKey).limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                            let name = snapshot.val().sender;
                            let value = snapshot.val().message;
                            let div = document.createElement("div");
                            let span = document.createElement("span");
                            span.innerHTML = "@"+ name;
                            let p = document.createElement("p");
                            p.innerHTML = value;
                            
                            div.appendChild(span);
                            div.appendChild(p);
                            
                            msgs.appendChild(div);
                            msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
                            console.log(snapshot.val().sender+': '+snapshot.val().message);
                            });
                }
            firebase.database().ref('messages/'+id).onDisconnect().remove();
            firebase.database().ref('connected/'+id).onDisconnect().update({
                  chattingWith: 'None'
                });
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + id).child('latitude').onDisconnect().remove();
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + id).child('longitude').onDisconnect().remove();
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + id).child('online').onDisconnect().set(false);
    }
  }, function() {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'error';
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <center>
  <div id="test" style="font-size:8vw;">Loading...</div></br>
  <div id ="authcode" style="font-size:10vw;"></div></br>
  <p>DISTANCE =</p> <span id = "distance"></span>

<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Chat</button>

<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
    <h1>Chat</h1>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div id = "messages">
    
    </div>
    <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
    <textarea id = "msgg" placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
</center>
<script>
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("msgg").value = null;
}

function sendMessage() {
        if(chattingWithKey != 'None')
        {
        var message=document.getElementById("msgg").value;
        //console.log('Message is '+message);
            firebase.database().ref('messages/'+id).push().set({
              "message": message,
              "sender": myName
            });
            document.getElementById('msgg').innerHTML = '';
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Particular Code I am talking about:

```
                        firebase.database().ref('messages/'+id).limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.val().sender == myName) {
                            let name = snapshot.val().sender;
                            let value = snapshot.val().message;
                            let div = document.createElement("div");
                            let span = document.createElement("span");
                            span.innerHTML = "@"+ name;
                            let p = document.createElement("p");
                            p.innerHTML = value;
                            
                            div.appendChild(span);
                            div.appendChild(p);
                            
                            msgs.appendChild(div);
                            msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
                            console.log(snapshot.val().sender+': '+snapshot.val().message);
                        }
                        });
                        
                        firebase.database().ref('messages/'+chattingWithKey).limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                            let name = snapshot.val().sender;
                            let value = snapshot.val().message;
                            let div = document.createElement("div");
                            let span = document.createElement("span");
                            span.innerHTML = "@"+ name;
                            let p = document.createElement("p");
                            p.innerHTML = value;
                            
                            div.appendChild(span);
                            div.appendChild(p);
                            
                            msgs.appendChild(div);
                            msgs.scrollTop = msgs.scrollHeight;
                            console.log(snapshot.val().sender+': '+snapshot.val().message);
                            });
```

Well, this code should automatically get called whenever a child is added. But it's just not working. To make it work, I have to add this code in a function which is needed to be called repeatedly (Which is making it worse as by doing this I am getting same data again and again). Can someone help me with this problem?